# Query with columns calculated at runtime

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I need some help with a query in SQL Server 2012.

My customer has a (sort of) internal wiki where his employees save documents; these documents are stored in a table in the database (let's call it `Documentation`, with columns `ID`, `Title`, `Text` and `Tags`) and accessed via a web frontend.

Up to now every employee had access to all the documents, now my customer now wants his employees to access only to specific procedures. There are no specific criteria such as role or user type, he wants to decide who sees what on an individual basis (from now on John will see documents 1,2 and 4 while Janet will see only documents 3,4 and 5 and so on). Don't ask me why...

My task is to prepare a big table in the frontend where every line is a document and the employees are in the column; for every document there is a checkbox for every employee, to indicate whether that user can access the document, something similar to this:

[image]

The problem is that the number of documents is not fixed, nor the number of employees. I need to find a query to extract this data without knowing the number of columns, it must be done dynamically at runtime.

I have access to the User Table of course, so I know the number and the name of the employees. As for the  authorizations I thought I could use a new table with just 3 columns: `ID`, `ID_Document` and `ID_User`.

I googled and searched but I could not find an appropriate answer. I tried using a Pivot Table but it does not seem right to me, I do not have to do any aggregation to the data.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The aggregation in the PIVOT doesn't have to mean anything. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: This solution isn't very scalable. You are looking for a dynamic pivot for display but it won't be that easy to update the underlying table.

Comment: So do you have normalised tables in your database, with a table for the users, documents, tags (as it appears that a document has many) and then the tables to link them? What does your data actually look like?

Comment: @Larnu there 3 tables involved: a table for the documents, one for the users and a new one for the authorizations

Comment: I agree @KeithL but the tables Documentation and Users are already there and the "big table" page seems to be mandatory for the customer

Comment: How about considering the Big Table as a display but allow users to edit on another screen and deal with just one document.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to we *assume* you have 5 tables in total. I'm going to call these `Document`, `Tag`, `Employee` and then `DocumentTag` and `DocumentEmployee`. To therefore get the solution you are after you need 2 different types of aggregation, string aggregation for the tags, and pivoting for the employees.

```
--Base tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.Document (DocumentID int, DocumentTitle nvarchar(50));

CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (EmployeeID int, EmployeeName nvarchar(50));

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tag (TagID int, TagName nvarchar(50));

GO
--Link tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.DocumentTag (DocumentID int, TagID int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.DocumentEmployee (DocumentID int, EmployeeID int);

GO
--Sample data

INSERT INTO dbo.Document
VALUES(2,N'Important Doc'),(3,N'New Doc');

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee
VALUES(1,N'John'),
      (2,N'Mary'),
      (3,N'Patricia'),
      (4,N'Paul');

INSERT INTO dbo.Tag
VALUES(1,N'Classified'),
      (2,N'Finance'),
      (3,N'Warehouse');
GO

--Link Data

INSERT INTO dbo.DocumentTag
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,3);

INSERT INTO dbo.DocumentEmployee
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,4);
```

If didn't need a dynamic pivot, then your SQL would look somethuing like this:

```
SELECT D.DocumentID,
       D.DocumentTitle,
       STUFF((SELECT N' ' + T.TagName
              FROM dbo.DocumentTag DT
                   JOIN dbo.Tag T ON DT.TagID = T.TagID
              WHERE DT.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
              FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') AS Tags,
       MAX(CASE E.EmployeeName WHEN N'John' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS John,
       MAX(CASE E.EmployeeName WHEN N'Mary' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mary,
       MAX(CASE E.EmployeeName WHEN N'Patricia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Patricia,
       MAX(CASE E.EmployeeName WHEN N'Paul' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Paul
FROM dbo.Document D
     JOIN dbo.DocumentEmployee DE ON D.DocumentID = DE.EmployeeID
     JOIN dbo.Employee E ON DE.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
GROUP BY D.DocumentID,
         D.DocumentTitle;
```

As you need the dataset to scale as you add employees, however, you need dynamic SQL to do this. So to achieve this using the above solution you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT D.DocumentID,' + @CRLF +
           N'       D.DocumentTitle,' + @CRLF +
           N'       STUFF((SELECT N'' '' + T.TagName' + @CRLF +
           N'              FROM dbo.DocumentTag DT' + @CRLF +
           N'                   JOIN dbo.Tag T ON DT.TagID = T.TagID' + @CRLF +
           N'              WHERE DT.DocumentID = D.DocumentID' + @CRLF +
           N'              FOR XML PATH(N''''),TYPE).value(''.'',''nvarchar(MAX)''),1,1,N'''') AS Tags,' + @CRLF +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF + 
                         N'       MAX(CASE E.EmployeeName WHEN N' + QUOTENAME(E.EmployeeName,'''') + N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(E.EmployeeName)
                  FROM dbo.Employee E
                  ORDER BY E.EmployeeID ASC
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.Document D' + @CRLF +
           N'     JOIN dbo.DocumentEmployee DE ON D.DocumentID = DE.EmployeeID' + @CRLF +
           N'     JOIN dbo.Employee E ON DE.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID' + @CRLF +
           N'GROUP BY D.DocumentID,' + @CRLF +
           N'         D.DocumentTitle;';

--PRINT @SQL; --YOur debugging friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61dd0a9b1979c35ad44c720dbf21bcf4)

Comment: Thank You @Larnu, it seems I was not clear in my post: I have 3 tables, Users - Documents - Authorizations. Thank You anyway for your reply

Comment: @SCdev unfortunately, without sample data, I **assumed** you had a fully normalised database. You *should* however, easily be able to change this so that for your denormalised tags; as you simply need to add the column to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` and remove the appropriate `FOR XML PATH` expression. This covered all the scenarios, however, if you don't need string aggregation, you actually have slightly simpler SQL to use.

Comment: this is still applicable. you are just not noramlizing your tags.

Comment: This is a good example on how to present the data, but that won't lead to an editable front end. I still think you need this to display and then have an edit button that allows you to work with 1 document.

Comment: No, the OP would need to handle the correct `INSERT`/`DELETE` statements in their front end, @KeithL .A `DELETE` for example, would be as easy as: `DELETE DE FROM dbo.DocumentEmployee DE JOIN dbo.Employee E ON DE.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID WHERE DE.DocumentID = @DocumentID AND E.EmployeeName = @EmployeeName;` (Of course, this *assumes* an employee's name is unique, a *foolish* assumption*, but then so does the OP's requirement.)